# how to convert a string to a Unix timestamp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, time, unix-timestamp

I want to convert a string `"2013-09-05 15:34:00"` into a Unix timestamp in javascript. Can any one tell how to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can initialise a Date object and call getTime() to get it in unix form. It comes out in milliseconds so you'll need to divide by 1000 to get it in seconds.

```
(new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime()/1000)
```

It may have decimal bits so wrapping it in Math.round would clean that.

```
Math.round(new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime()/1000)
```

Comment: That is gonna also convert the given datetime to your local time in timestamp.

Comment: It's also not guaranteed to work with that string format.

Answer (score 12):

try

```
(new Date("2013-09-05 15:34:00")).getTime() / 1000
```

Answer (score 7):

[DaMouse404](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2740208/damouse404) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18634180/1717821) works, but instead of using dashes, you will use slashes:

You can initialise a Date object and call getTime() to get it in unix form. It comes out in milliseconds so you'll need to divide by 1000 to get it in seconds.

```
(new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime()/1000)
```

It may have decimal bits so wrapping it in Math.round would clean that.

```
Math.round(new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime()/1000)
```

Comment: `(new Date("2013-09-05 15:34:00").replace(/-/g, '/').getTime()/1000)` be careful when using replace function, you should use `g`, otherwise it will only convert the first dash. I waste a lot of time on this.

Comment: I'm not sure why the last comment was upvoted. A `Date` object does not have a `replace` method. Also, this answer is incorrect; using slashes produces the incorrect format for guaranteed parsing by `Date.parse` (what is used by `new Date(string)`). See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552).

Answer (score 5):

For this you should check out the moment.s-library

Using that you could write something like:

```js
newUnixTimeStamp = moment('2013-09-05 15:34:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').unix();
```

Comment: I think the right format for minutes is `mm`. So the second argument of `moment` is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 3):

I would go with date parse myself since it is the native solution. [MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```
const datetimeString = '04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT';
const unixTimestamp = Date.parse(datetimeString);
// unixTimestamp = 818035920000
```

Comment: `new Date(string)` uses `Date.parse`. Also, you shouldn't use `Date.parse` on arbitrary formats. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552).