# Convert dd-mm-yyyy hr:min:sec to unixtime

Tags: javascript, date, format, unix-timestamp

I have a date string of the format dd-mm-yyyy hr:min:sec (time in 24 hour format). How do I convert this string into unix time. I know in php if I write `time()` gives me unixtime. I am trying to achieve the same result from the date string using javascript.

```
    var expTime = document.getElementById("expiryDT").value; 
    //the value inside this element is the date with (dd-mm-yyyy hr:min:sec) format.
var todayUnixTime = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
//this gives me the unixtime in seconds for today, ready to pass into php
```

How do I convert the string `expTime` into a unixtime in javascript, so that I can pass it to php;

```
var expTime = String(document.getElementById("expiryDT").value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N4T5h/2/

Comment: Someone posts all steps here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18634180/1717821

:)

Comment: when I use the code in that link , and tried to alert the converted expTime it is giving me an NaN error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Date doesn't recognize your date format (dd-mm-yyyy hr:min:sec). Use a valid RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date format, or use the other form of the Date constructor that takes numeric arguments:

```
new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N4T5h/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. Works ! :)

Comment: @JINSOUL the code in that example is pretty brittle, it's really just meant to be an example. If the value isn't in exactly the format you gave, things will break. Just a heads-up.

Comment: Thanks, I made it sure in the php, also made it only readable.

Answer (score 1):

[Jinsoul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766825/jinsoul) you're right there is an error on format try this instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20570223/1717821

Answer (score 0):

`var unixTime = Math.round(new Date('January 21,2013 23:14:12').getTime()/1000);`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 var someDate = new Date(Date.parse(expTime));
```

Answer (score -1):

use `getTime()` method
here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/N4T5h/

Comment: Your fiddle makes sense and I know it is working but for some damn reason when I use the code and try to alert it is saying invalid date `var expTime = String(document.getElementById("expiryDT").value); 
 alert(expTime); // alerts proper date which is inside the field.
 expTime = new Date(expTime);
 alert(expTime);    //alerts invalid Date `

Comment: that is because javascript Date support "mm-dd-yyyy hr:min:sec" and not dd-mm-yyyy hr:min:sec. so you have to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/N4T5h/4/