# How to check if one date is before another date using JavaScript\JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am absolutely new in JavaScript development and I have to perform the following task: I have 2 **input** tag containing 2 string representing date in the form **01/12/2014** (**DAY/MONTH/YEAR**). I use this input tag to search objects that have a date field that is among these dates.

```
<input type="hidden" size="9" class="impPrfTot" readonly="readonly"
                                           onchange="cambioDataDa(this.value)"
                                           name="dataDa" id="datada" value="<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("dataDa")%>"
                                           style="font-size: 11px;color: #000000;">

<input type="hidden" size="9" class="impPrfTot" readonly="readonly"
                                           onchange="cambioDataA(this.value); checkData(this.value)"
                                           name="dataA" id="dataa" value="<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("dataA")%>"
                                           style="font-size: 11px;color: #000000;">

<button class="dataDadataAButton" name="submitdataDadataA" onclick="sottomettiFormDataDaA(this)">Cerca</button>
```

And finally I have a **button** used to submit this form using this JavaScript:

```
function sottomettiFormDataDaA(obj) {
    document.getElementById('dataDaAForm').submit();
}
```

What I need is to prevent that the value inside **dataA** (in English language dateTo) input is previous that **dataDa** value (in English language **dateFrom**).

I am trying to do something like this:

1. The JavaScript is called at the **onchange** event on the change of a data and take the dataA string (tha represent the dateTo date) and check if it is previous of the dataA (the dateTo date).
2. If the previous check is true the date range is invalid so the script show an error popup message and disallow the submit of the form having id="dataDaAForm"

   ```
   function checkData(dataA) {
       dataDa = document.getElementById('dataDa').value;

       if(dataDa > dataA){
           // SHOW A POPUP ERROR MESSAGE
           // DISALLOW THE FORM SUBMIT
       }
   }
   ```

Bue I have really not idea about complete this JavaScript and I don't know it exist better solution to achieve this task.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery check [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) To compare dates you can then use `Date.compare ( Date date1, Date date2 ) `

Comment: I don't think you need jQuery for datejs. Another fine date library i used is http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @VDesign using a library for this simple task is simply absurd. Think before you type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only need to compare the date without the time use this:

```js
// convert date format to "YYYY-MM-DD"
var a = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)
// get date from input field, by default is "YYYY-MM-DD" format
var b = document.getElementById('datePicker').value

// compare
console.log(a == b)
console.log(a > b)
console.log(a < b)
```

```html
<input id="datePicker" type="date" />
```

Comment: There is also a `toISOString()` that returns the same. What is the difference?

Answer (score 69):

Very simple, `Date` instance can be compared directly.

```
function compareTime(time1, time2) {
    return new Date(time1) > new Date(time2); // true if time1 is later
}
```

When you compare two `Date` instance, or minus one another, the `valueOf` method will be called internally, which convert the instance to timestamp (**millisecond accurate**).

Answer (score 21):

This will work:

```
function dateCompare(date1, date2){
    return new Date(date2) > new Date(date1);
}
```

Returns `true` if `date2` is later, `false` otherwise. Call with `dateCompare('01/12/2014', '02/24/2014')`.

```js
function dateCompare(date1, date2){
    return new Date(date2) > new Date(date1);
}

// Demo (uses jQuery)

$("tbody tr").each(function(){
    $tr = $(this);
    $td = $tr.children('td');
    date1 = $td.eq(0).text();
    date2 = $td.eq(1).text();
    result = dateCompare(date1,date2);
    $td.eq(2).text(result);
    if($td.eq(2).text() == $td.eq(3).text()) $tr.css('background','green');
    else $tr.css('background','red');
});
```

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>date1</td>
            <td>date2</td>
            <td>Result</td>
            <td>Expected</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>01/12/2014</td>
            <td>02/24/2014</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>true</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>01/12/2013</td>
            <td>02/24/2012</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>false</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>01/12/2014</td>
            <td>02/24/2018</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>true</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>01/12/2015</td>
            <td>02/24/2011</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>false</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usas1tu6/), if you prefer.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It's from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18634180/1234256). Inaccurate to a second, at most.

Comment: By why round at all if you are using seconds? Surely you need to truncate to the closest date (i.e. midnight).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I don't need to divide it at all, really.

Comment: You don't even need to use `getTime()` as dates can be compared directly with `>`.