# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to unix timestamp in angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a query how do I convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to ***UNIX time-stamp*** using **angularjs or JavaScript** for example:`2015-04-17 10:12:12`this is how my date value how do i convert ??

Comment: `+new Date('2015-04-17 10:12:12')` - it will return a int value

Comment: I tried that when am doing it I am receiving INVALID DATE as output when console logged the above one.

Comment: then you will have to use a good parse like momentjs to parse the string to date then get the timestamp value from that

Comment: How about `Date.parse('2015-04-17 10:12:12')` ? See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: [Convert a string to a Unix timestamp in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18634087/769678)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3kLf4mhw/2/ - using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @arun momentjs are you refering to this link http://momentjs.com/

Comment: ok thanks man let me try it out

Answer (score 8):

```
new Date("2015/04/29 11:24:00").getTime(); //for answer in milliseconds
(new Date("2015/04/29 11:24:00").getTime()/1000); //to get answer in seconds
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
date1 = '2015-04-17 10:12:12'.split(':');
date2 = date1[0].split(' ');
date3 = date2[0].split('-');
the_date = new Date(parseInt(date3[0]),parseInt(date3[1])-1,parseInt(date3[2]),parseInt(date2[1]),parseInt(date1[1]),parseInt(date1[2]));
```

Comment: this does not answer OP's question. The original date format is not like this

Comment: Well, you could transform to this format with [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: ouch, that works, but it would be over-complicated. And `date3[1]` is `04` (a string) ... forget to use `parseInt()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below snippet for unix timestamp...

```
var unixtimestamp = (new Date('2015-04-17 10:12:12')).getTime() / 1000;
```

Sorry my above solution was working fine in only Chrome.

Below soltution might help you..

```
var unixtimestamp = (new Date("2015-04-17 10:12:12".replace('-','/'))).getTime() / 1000;
        alert(unixtimestamp);
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7r4c9Lqo/3/

Comment: Working js fiddle link, http://jsfiddle.net/7r4c9Lqo/