# How to process data before set or get operation?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using primeNG calendar and I got a model called myDate and a dateformat. ngModel directive referencing to a Date property.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="myDate"  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
```

But problem is I want to store myDate value as Unix Timestamp. So I need to convert myDate to milliseconds before set and convert it to date object with dateformat before get operation. Is there any way to do this?

```
private myDate;

setMyDate(myNewDate){
    this.myDate = convertDateToTimestamp(myNewDate)
}

getMyDate(){
   return convertTimestampToDate(this.myDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call getTime() on this date object to get it in unix form. It comes out in milliseconds.

```
new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime();
```

It may have decimal bits so wrapping it in Math.round would clean that.

```
Math.round(new Date("2013/09/05 15:34:00").getTime());
```

[how to convert a string to a Unix timestamp in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634087/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-unix-timestamp-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use getters and setters to achieve this, which is actually very close to what you already have:

```
private _myDate;

set myDate(myNewDate){
    this._myDate = convertDateToTimestamp(myNewDate)
}

get myDate(){
   return convertTimestampToDate(this._myDate)
}
```